# I tried to install Ubuntu using Unetbootin but I keep getting status 0x000007b from the windows boot manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, unetbootin

The Windows boot manager (don’t know why the windows boot manager is running), is saying that I’m missing required files or that there are errors in my files, but I’m pretty sure I followed the steps to use Unet correctly.

What I see:

“Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer
2. 2. Choose your language settings, and then click “next”
3. Click “repair your computer”

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.

File: \unn1dr.mbr

Status: 0x000007b

Info: the application or operating system couldn’t be loaded because a required file is missing or contains errors.”

Here’s how I installed using Unetbootin
I installed Unetbootin as well as the Ubuntu-20.04.3 Disc Image File.

I launched Unetbootin and selected disk image, iso, and the Ubuntu DIF in my downloads directory

Then I clicked “type” and changed it to hard disk and told it to install it to my C drive. I then pressed okay.

After it was done loading I reset my pc and tried to select Unetbootin on my pc’s launch, which is where I’m encountering the issue I’m having now.

I only have this problem when I try to load into Unetbootin, I can still load into windows ten.

Comment: you seem to have bricked your efi partition. A mbr file  should not exists in a windows 10 environment. Describe in your question how you installed Ubuntu with Unetbootin (parameters etc) in the first place. Use the "edit" link below your question to fill the missing infos.

Comment: @kanehekili I added those details to my question

Comment: This is the basic stuff you need to know -> [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi) . Make adjustments for your specific hardware where needed and, of course, stop messing with Unetbootin if you don't know how to use it.

Comment: Try with a "standard" install as in the link provided by ChanganAuto. I don't mess with Unetbootin either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Impossible to Install Linux on Notebook G75VX with Win8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325070/impossible-to-install-linux-on-notebook-g75vx-with-win8)